# Why is my microbit (in the ide and in real life) only playing 2 beats on the startMelody function

Tags: javascript, bbc-microbit

Currently I'm in the midst of trying to play a song (you may recognize) on my micro-bit, but instead of playing the song it'll play 3 beats of the same tone (2 if I have it at the default bpm). Here's my code

```
let amongUs = ['c3:0.5', 'd#3:0.5', 'f3:0.5', 'f#3:0.5', 'f3:0.5',
 'eb3:0.5', 'c3:1.5', 'bb3:0.25', 'd3:0.25', 'c3:1', 'r:1',
  'c2:0.5', 'g2:.5']

music.startMelody(amongUs);
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions that may fix this, not just to mine but a general fix that will work for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have no idea why I didn't try this but I guess I hope this helps people having a similar problem.

The beat system in the micro:bit IDE is way off so instead of using beats as little as .5 you'll want to use beats of at least 1.

-Emily

Comment: You can also alter the tempo with "setTempo".

Comment: Great to know! Thank you :)